# Reverse-engineer C++ files from APK

Tags: java, android, c++, apk, reverse-engineering

I want to decompile an Android Package (APK) of a game because I wanna study that source code. But the only code that I can see is the Java one (all obfuscated and of the server). What I want is too see the client code (almost 80% of app) written in C++. I've tried so many decompilers but noone can show me the C++ code. Only Java/XML/resources.

Thanks in advance,
Rocco

Comment: How did you measure the coverage of the client code that is 80% if you could not see it?

Comment: I see the size. Note that the APK file is also compressed...

Comment: The APK is ~90MB. The java code is 3,9MB, the res is 2MB

Comment: well, APK's are zip files in another form, hence *"Note that the APK file is also compressed..."*

Comment: I mean, the compressed APK is ~90MB, the uncompressed full apk should be ~110MB...

Comment: Start of programming first by creating a small game first, learn how the mechanics work, (there are plenty of resources outside of here for this!) Then develop an android app, to get an understanding, then see how far you go. this question, while too broad, you are in the deep end, and will only serve to frustrate yourself.

Comment: I'm already developing Android apps. All I wanna know is how the technologies of that app work, so I can make a similar app.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: k. I'm new to StackOverflow, I will keep this on mind.

Comment: This is pretty shady and borderline illegal. Check the laws applying in your country before proceeding.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried to diassemble & decompile program such as snowman's decompiler?
It will decompile it to C++ language.